# How to send headers in api with body empty using axios in react js.?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, response

I'm trying to send an api call with access token in the header and empty body i'm sending the exact way but for some reasons it keeps on giving me error 401 which is Unauthorized i can't find the bug in it and i'm unable to resolve it.

My API call

```
export const resendSmsCode = (userdata) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(true));
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://theappsouk.com/api/Profile/ReGenerateSmsCode",
      {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userdata.auth}`,    
      }
    );
    const { data } = response;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(false));
    dispatch({
      type: RESEND_SMS_CODE,
      payload: data,
    });
  };
};
```

[image: You can see in the picture its getting the api call]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like header options is supposed to be placed in the 3rd argument. But you placed it at 2nd argument which it sends your header as payload.

Here is the correct one:

```js
const response = await axios.post(
  "https://theappsouk.com/api/Profile/ReGenerateSmsCode",
  void 0,
  {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${userdata.auth}`,    
  }
);
```

Comment: I have tried it but it didnt work @tmhao2005

Comment: Really. Can you replace `void 0` (undefined) with an empty object `{}` then?

Comment: can you answer this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232921/how-to-call-an-event-on-successful-api-response-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

If you want to send **headers**, you have to write the following:

```js
const response = await axios.post(
    "https://theappsouk.com/api/Profile/ReGenerateSmsCode",
    {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userdata.auth}` 
        } 
    }
);
```

PS: When posting questions, I would black out auth tokens or passwords (like in your screenshot). Just make sure to invalidate this token.

Comment: Thanks i have tried this before but the api response remained the same can you answer this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232921/how-to-call-an-event-on-successful-api-response-in-react-js